# Elasticsearch: filtering search suggestions with multiple contexts

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I'm attempting to filter search suggestions by multiple conditions in Elasticsearch 5.0+. For example, as a user types, we'd say "Here are suggestions that meet both criteria X AND criteria Y". My understanding is that the way to do that is with contexts and categories as defined here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.3/suggester-context.html

However, I also found this Github issue saying that these contexts were changed in 5.x to be OR'd together when they had previously been AND'd: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/21291

Does this mean this goal is impossible in Elasticsearch? The Github issue is from November, and it seems like this is a big loss/change in functionality.

Comment: It is WIP : https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/24565